# RedShift GROUP BY Constant Column Gives Inconsistent Results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I was wondering if anyone could help explain why using `GROUP BY` on a constant column that is `VARCHAR` vs. one that is `INTEGER` gives different behaviours.

Here is my minimal working example. The following table mocks the real-world data for which I found this problem off of:

```
CREATE TABLE test.show_bug AS

WITH integers AS (
    SELECT 0 AS num
    UNION SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION SELECT 2 AS num
    UNION SELECT 3 AS num
    UNION SELECT 4 AS num
    UNION SELECT 5 AS num
)
SELECT 
    '2017-03-16' + mod(a.num, 2) AS date_time 
    , CASE mod(b.num, 3)
        WHEN 0 THEN 'source_a'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'source_b'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'source_c'
        END AS user_source
    , b.num || a.num || b.num || a.num || b.num AS user_id
FROM integers AS a
CROSS JOIN integers AS b
;
```

This looks like:

```
 date_time  | user_source | user_id
------------+-------------+---------
 2017-03-17 | source_a    | 3113313
 2017-03-17 | source_b    | 4114414
 2017-03-17 | source_b    | 1111111
 2017-03-16 | source_a    | 0000000
 2017-03-16 | source_c    | 2442242
 2017-03-16 | source_c    | 5225525
....
(36 rows)
```

Essentially I want to be able to `COUNT` (for each day) the number of users, number of sources, and the amount of users per source. However, I have two different tables of the same format from which I want to `UNION` the results together. I can differentiate these results by adding a constant column to each: `app_1` and `app_2`.

For the sake of example I'm using the same mock table twice, but in real-world application I have two different tables, either way the following sql should get my desired result:

```
SELECT 
    'app_1' AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2

UNION

SELECT 
    'app_2' AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

This results in

```
   app    |     date_trunc      | count | count1 | count2
----------+---------------------+-------+--------+--------
 app_1    | 2017-03-16 00:00:00 |     2 |      1 |      0
 app_1    | 2017-03-17 00:00:00 |     2 |      1 |      0
 app_1    | 2017-03-19 00:00:00 |     5 |      0 |      1
 app_2    | 2017-03-19 00:00:00 |     7 |      1 |      0
 app_1    | 2017-03-16 00:00:00 |     0 |      1 |      0
....
(112 rows)
```

which is not correct because what I'd actually expect is the result attained from using the integer values `1` and `2` in place of the `VARCHAR` values `app_1` and `app_2`, i.e. like:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2

UNION

SELECT 
    2 AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

which gives me:

```
   app    |     date_trunc      | count | count1 | count2
----------+---------------------+-------+--------+--------
        1 | 2017-03-16 00:00:00 |   192 |     16 |    192
        1 | 2017-03-17 00:00:00 |   208 |     14 |    208
        1 | 2017-03-18 00:00:00 |   203 |     14 |    203
        1 | 2017-03-19 00:00:00 |   203 |     14 |    203
        1 | 2017-03-20 00:00:00 |    35 |      0 |     35
        2 | 2017-03-16 00:00:00 |   192 |     16 |    192
        2 | 2017-03-17 00:00:00 |   208 |     14 |    208
        2 | 2017-03-18 00:00:00 |   203 |     14 |    203
        2 | 2017-03-19 00:00:00 |   203 |     14 |    203
        2 | 2017-03-20 00:00:00 |    35 |      0 |     35
```

This effect is also seen if I don't use the `UNION`.

There are some obvious workarounds to get the result I desire, however the fundamental issue here is that there seems to be an unintuitive difference in behaviour with the use of `VARCHAR` constant columns instead of `INTEGER` constant columns.

If someone could help me understand what this difference is I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: For the sake of things I've filed a bug with AWS support two weeks ago. I will update with an answer once they reply...

Comment: Have you received an explanation from AWS Support?  
I've faced a similar issue and currently am skipping the GROUP BY on constant values (literals).

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you found a genuine bug in Amazon Redshift, or at least a behaviour that is undesired.

I managed to narrow it down to:

- Only when a `VARCHAR` is used as one of the GROUP BY, and
- When using multiple `COUNT(DISTINCT)` statements

So, this simple statement also produces too many results:

```
SELECT 
    '1',
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_source),
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM show_bug
GROUP BY 1
```

Yet this is okay:

```
SELECT 
    '1'::INTEGER,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_source),
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM show_bug
GROUP BY 1
```

Removing either of the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` entries also makes it work fine.

If you are subscribed to AWS Support, I recommend that you lodge a bug report. If you are not subscribed to support, you can lodge it via the AWS Support Forums, but they will not have guaranteed response times.

Comment: `'1'::INTEGER` can be simplified to `1`

Comment: Casting the string literal to a specific type seems to correct the result: `SELECT '1'::CHAR(10), COUNT(DISTINCT user_source), COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM show_bug GROUP BY 1`

Answer (score 0):

Casting the literal to a specific type changes the behavior but still gives inconsistent results. Using UNION ALL avoids obscuring some of the problem and some queries below will return more results.

With CHAR get 4 rows:

```
SELECT
    'app_1'::CHAR(5) AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2
UNION
SELECT
    'app_2'::CHAR(5) AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2

  app  | date_time  | count | count1 | count2
-------+------------+-------+--------+--------
 app_2 | 2017-03-16 |    18 |      3 |     18
 app_1 | 2017-03-17 |    18 |      3 |     18
 app_1 | 2017-03-16 |    18 |      3 |     18
 app_2 | 2017-03-17 |    18 |      3 |     18
(4 rows)
```

VARCHAR gives different result:

```
SELECT
    'app_1'::VARCHAR(10) AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2
UNION
SELECT
    'app_2'::VARCHAR(10) AS app
    , date_time
    , COUNT(user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_source)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM test.show_bug
GROUP BY 1, 2

  app  | date_time  | count | count1 | count2
-------+------------+-------+--------+--------
 app_1 | 2017-03-16 |     3 |      1 |      0
 app_1 | 2017-03-17 |     3 |      1 |      0
 app_2 | 2017-03-17 |     0 |      1 |      0
 app_2 | 2017-03-16 |     3 |      1 |      0
 app_2 | 2017-03-17 |     0 |      0 |      1
 app_1 | 2017-03-16 |     0 |      0 |      1
 app_2 | 2017-03-16 |     0 |      0 |      1
 app_1 | 2017-03-17 |     0 |      1 |      0
 app_2 | 2017-03-16 |     0 |      1 |      0
 app_1 | 2017-03-16 |     0 |      1 |      0
 app_1 | 2017-03-17 |     0 |      0 |      1
 app_2 | 2017-03-17 |     3 |      1 |      0
(12 rows)
```

Using an INT gives same result as CHAR above.

Wow, this is scary. Now I have to go look at all our queries that use literals like this to categorize a result set.